# <Accelerate/Accelerate.h> not found when building on device

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, mp3

I'm trying to include an MP3 reader that I found on Github (DOUAudioStreamer), first everything works like a charm when I test on simulator, but when I try to build this project into my iPhone 5, I get an error  **file not found**

I tried removing the library from **Linked Frameworks** to include it again but there's no Accelerate.Framework when search it, even before I remove it, it was written in red.

I was able to build the project and run it on simulator without adding the framework, so I suppose including the header is enough to use it.

I did some research about it, and tried some tricks but no success, so what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your target and in the build phases tab link the Accelerate.framework library to your project. Its added under Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: no, the problem is deeper, Accelerate.Framework is not available when I search it in **Link Binary With Libraries**

Comment: I found the solution, **Accelerate.Framework** is missed in **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks** , so I took this framework file from another developer's mac, and paste it on my Frameworks folder mentioned above, and everything works :/

Comment: Thats odd that the complete framework was missing, however I'm glad you got it working.